# Discrete Math On inductions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the sequence defined by the formula a_n = n+3, satisfies the recurrence relation a_n = 2a_n-1 - a_n-2 ,for all n ≥ 2.

I know this is a induction problem and I think I have to set n= n+1 but I'm not sure that how would I show the recurrence relation between them.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** an induction problem. We have 
$$2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=2(n-1+3)-(n-2+3)=n+3=a_n.$$